# pgfplots: replace scatter markers with custom text

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm wondering if it's possible using pgfplot to plot a 3D scatter plot with lines between each point where the point is replaced with a value. Image is shown below.

[image]

Currently I am populating the points on the graph via:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{table2.csv}
Name,X,Y,Z
0,    0,    0,    0
1,    0,    1 ,   0
2,    0,    2 ,   0
3,    0 ,   3  ,  0
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    grid=both, xlabel=$X$,ylabel=$Y$,zlabel=$Z$,
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{Name} \as \labela},
    nodes near coords={\labela},
    nodes near coords align={horizontal}
        ]

    \addplot3[scatter,only marks] table [x=X,y=Y,z=Z,col sep=comma] {table2.csv};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the mark type `text` and adjust accordingly. If the labels are just the coordinate indices of the points then you can use the readily available `\coordindex` macro instead without an extra column.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    grid=both, xlabel=$X$,ylabel=$Y$,zlabel=$Z$,
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{Name} \as \labela},
        ]

    \addplot3[scatter,only marks,mark = text,
              mark options={text mark=\labela,
                            text mark as node=true,
                            text mark style={circle,inner sep=1pt,draw}
                            }
              ] 
    table [x=X,y=Y,z=Z,col sep=comma] {
    Name,X,Y,Z
    0,    0,    0,    0
    1,    0,    1 ,   0
    2,    0,    2 ,   0
    3,    0 ,   3  ,  0
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]